# Enabling indexing for version store in alfresco (solr-search subsystem)

Tags: java, search, lucene, alfresco

Is there any way to enable indexing for version2Store in alfresco?.
I'm using Alfresco 4.2.c & solr-search subsystem.

My requirement is as follows:

User will search based on content in alfresco. If a word is not present in latest version but present in previous version then search result should display older version. But if I put lucene query against version2Store nothing is listed since it is not indexed. How to enable indexing for version2Store. Please help me in this regard.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What did you tried yet? Pls stop asking for a ready meal

Comment: I have developed my own content management application using alfresco web services. There are two workspaces in alfresco , spacesstore and version2store. By default alfresco will store in spacesstore and it will be indexed. Alfresco maintains the versions of the all contents in version2store. I found that version2Store will not be indexed. I tried searching how to change this default behaviour. I didn't get anything. Then I tried directly quering version2Store using the java api's. Again no use. So I posted this question

Comment: well, which Alfresco version do you use. Are you sure that you're using lucene search-subystem and not solr as default since 4.0?

Comment: I used alfresco 4.2c community edition. No I am using solr subsystem itself. But SOLR inturn uses lucene quries itself right?. Is it not possible to configure SOLR itself for searching in version2Store?

Comment: ok that changes a lot: you'll have to tweak the solr subsystem to index the version2Store

Answer (score 0):

As discussed via comments we are talking about the SOLR search subsystem here.

Please take a look into the Alfresco wiki here & post another more detailed questions if you're still struggling: http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Alfresco_And_SOLR#Configuring_query_against_additional_stores

You should also keep in mind that just adding the store into the index does not include the store in your queries automatically. Take a look into org.alfresco.service.cmr.search.SearchParameters.addStore(...)

AFAIK it's only possible to execute a search for 1 store only as the stores are handled as SOLR cores internally.

Comment: I followed the steps given in the document. Once doing that I found that a new core has been added inside {alf_data}/solr. But again when I run my code against the versionStore i am getting exception saying solr support for workspace://version2Store is not supported

Comment: My code is as follws 
   Store storeRef = new Store(Constants.WORKSPACE_STORE, "version2Store");
   
   RepositoryServiceSoapBindingStub repositoryService = WebServiceFactory.getRepositoryService();
   String luceneQuery = "PATH:\"/app:company_home/*\" AND TEXT:\"*demo*\"";
   System.out.println(luceneQuery); 
   Query query = new Query(Constants.QUERY_LANG_LUCENE, luceneQuery);
   QueryResult queryResult = repositoryService.query(storeRef, query,false);
   ResultSet resultSet = queryResult.getResultSet();
   System.out.println(resultSet.getTotalRowCount());

Comment: Exception thrown is "/app:company_home/*" AND TEXT:"*demo*"
AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.generalException
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: 
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
 {http://www.alfresco.org/ws/service/repository/1.0}RepositoryFault:<ns1:errorCode>0</ns1:errorCode><ns1:message>org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 00230007 No solr query support for store workspace://version2Store</ns1:message>
 {http://xml.apache.org/axis/

Comment: Have you tried this and successfully done?. If yes can you plz explain me in details the steps to achieve this

Comment: no - havn't tried that with version2Store yet, here is a ticket related to the stuff https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ALF-18999

Comment: But there also telling they are not successfull..:(

Comment: imho it should be technically possible, but you'll need to have deep knowledge of the the alfresco repo code. If it's possible to implement your use case is unclear as you didn't mentioned what you want to achieve from an end-user perspective